# Table that got double border

Tags: html, css

I created this table but I can't get rid off the double border inside.

Any suggestions, how can I resolve that without changing too much?

I searched other people problems, but it mostly ends with adding border-collapse
but that couldn't help me
the collapse helps with borders but it is not completely  vanished

```html
      <table class="TB1">
        <tr>
          <th><p>AIDS/HIV</p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="1-radio">
                Yes
              </label>
              
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="1-radio">
                No
              </label>
            </th>
          <th> <th><p>Alcohol Use/Abuse</p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="2-radio">
                Yes
              </label>
              
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="2-radio">
                No
              </label></th>
          <th> <th><p>Anemia</p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="3-radio">
                Yes
              </label>
              
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="3-radio">
                No
              </label></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><p>Angina/Chest Pain </p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="4-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="4-radio">
                  No
                </label>
              </th>
            <th> <th><p>Asthma</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="5-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="5-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
            <th> <th><p>Blood Disease</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="6-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="6-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><p>Cancer</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="7-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="7-radio">
                  No
                </label>
              </th>
            <th> <th><p>Chemotherapy</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="8-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="8-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
            <th> <th><p>Any Heart Disorder </p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="9-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="9-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><p>Diabetes</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="0-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="0-radio">
                  No
                </label>
              </th>
            <th> <th><p>Hepatitis B</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="11-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="11-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
            <th> <th><p>Hepatitis C </p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="12-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="12-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><p>High Blood Pressure</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="13-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="13-radio">
                  No
                </label>
              </th>
            <th> <th><p>Low Blood Pressure</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="14-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="14-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
            <th> <th><p>Renal Dialysis</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="15-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="15-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><p>TB</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="16-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="16-radio">
                  No
                </label>
              </th>
            <th> <th><p>Jaundice</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="17-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="17-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
            <th> <th><p>Lung Disease</p>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="18-radio">
                  Yes
                </label>
                
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="18-radio">
                  No
                </label></th>
          </tr>
                  
      </table>
        .TB1{
        
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    
    .TB1   th{
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had some empty extra `<th>` tags in your code and browsers renders these as a empty, small table-cell

Try this:

```css
 .TB1{
    
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.TB1   th{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <table class="TB1">
    <tr>
      <th><p>AIDS/HIV</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="1-radio">
            Yes
          </label>
          
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="1-radio">
            No
          </label>
        </th>
      <th><p>Alcohol Use/Abuse</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="2-radio">
            Yes
          </label>
          
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="2-radio">
            No
          </label></th>
      <th><p>Anemia</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="3-radio">
            Yes
          </label>
          
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="3-radio">
            No
          </label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><p>Angina/Chest Pain </p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="4-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="4-radio">
              No
            </label>
          </th>
         <th><p>Asthma</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="5-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="5-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
         <th><p>Blood Disease</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="6-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="6-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><p>Cancer</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="7-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="7-radio">
              No
            </label>
          </th>
        <th><p>Chemotherapy</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="8-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="8-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
         <th><p>Any Heart Disorder </p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="9-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="9-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><p>Diabetes</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="0-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="0-radio">
              No
            </label>
          </th>
         <th><p>Hepatitis B</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="11-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="11-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
        <th><p>Hepatitis C </p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="12-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="12-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><p>High Blood Pressure</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="13-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="13-radio">
              No
            </label>
          </th>
         <th><p>Low Blood Pressure</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="14-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="14-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
        <th><p>Renal Dialysis</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="15-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="15-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><p>TB</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="16-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="16-radio">
              No
            </label>
          </th>
        <th><p>Jaundice</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="17-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="17-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
        <th><p>Lung Disease</p>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="18-radio">
              Yes
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="18-radio">
              No
            </label></th>
      </tr>
              
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks man , i never would have found it :)